# Ordering Data Frame in R compared to CSV

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

I was testing a bar chart with plotly in R and managed to order the data to show largest bar first. This was done with the following code:

```
plot_data <- 
  read.csv('plot_data.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  arrange(plot_data$Value)
```

However now that I can get it to work I want to transfer it into my R Shiny dashboard and I can't transfer the code to read the normal data frame rather than the .csv file. I have tried the following:

```
Plot_Data <- State_data()
Plot_Data <- arrange(Plot_Data$Value)
```

However I'm still not getting it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [arrange](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) with the right parameters (indicating the data frame if you are not using the pipes). Please find below a working example:

```
Plot_Data <- data.frame(
  Name = c('One', 'Two', 'Three'),
  Value = c(200, 100, 300)
)
Plot_Data <- arrange(Plot_Data, Value)
```

This will sort your data frame by `Value` in ascending order. If you want it in descending order, you need to use `arrange(Plot_Data, desc(Value))`